# Last command's output is doubled (trying to print stack elements)

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

So, the task is to implement simple stack using array and to write a program that calls stack methods using command line commands. For example:

- `set_size 5` – calls  a function that returns stack with 5 elements
- `push N` – calls stack.push(N)
- `pop` - calls stack.pop()
- `print` – calls stack print

The corresponding code is below. :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>

template <class T>
class Stack
{
    int size = 0;
    T* Array;
    int top = 0;

public:
    Stack(size_t Size);
    ~Stack()
    {
        delete[] Array;
    }
    void push(T element);
    void pop();
    void print();
};
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(size_t Size)
{
    size = Size;
    top = -1;
    Array = new T[size];
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T element)
{
    if (top >= (size - 1))
    {
        std::cout << "overflow" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Array[++top] = element;
    }
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (top < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "underflow" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << Array[top--] << std::endl;
    }

}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print()
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
    }
    int i = -1;
    while (++i <= top)
    {
        std::cout << Array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
template <class T>
Stack<T> set_size(int Size)
{
    return Stack<T>(Size);
}

int main()
{   
    int size = 0;
    std::string command, line, element;
    std::cin >> command >> size;
    if (command == "set_size")
    {
        auto stack = set_size<std::string>(size);
        while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::istringstream is(line);
            is >> command;
            if (command == "push")
            {
                is >> element;
                if (is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
                {
                    stack.push(element);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            if (command == "pop")
            {
                stack.pop();
            }
            if (command == "print")
            {
                stack.print();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason the testing utility's output differs from the one I get in Visual Studio – last command is repeated twice. Utility's input:

```
set_size 5
pop
push 1 10
push 2
push 3
push 4
push 5
print
push 6
pop
push 7
print
```

**EDIT:** For some reason when pressing *enter* in command line it repeats the previous command, so that's why the utility repeats last `print`. But I still don't know why and how to fix this.

And here are the outputs:

Utility:

```
underflow
error
2 3 4 5 
6
2 3 4 5 7 
2 3 4 5 7
```

The desired output (the one I also get in Visual Studio):

```
underflow
error
2 3 4 5
6
2 3 4 5 7
```

I reckon it is somehow related to the usage of *istringstream* or the way my commands are inputted, but I can't figure out why it differs and how to fix it. Or are there ways to do it smarter / simpler? 
(Note: I need to check if there is only 1 `push` argument, so the whole *istringstream* thing is meant to do exactly this)

Comment: I'm not getting a duplicate on my end.

Comment: @0x499602D2
The duplicate appears when pressing enter with no input – the last command is repeated. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter an empty string the subsequent input operation `is >> command` will fail, leaving `command` with the value it had last, which is `print`. To fix this, either create a local variable to work with inside the loop, or call `command.clear()` before the input operation.